# Testing Angular factory that uses OpenLayers

Tags: angularjs, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am writing a map abstraction layer using openlayers and an Angular factory to share the API. I am trying to use jasmine to test it but OpenLayers doesn't seem to be playing nice.

```
describe("add Group", function(){
 var map;
 beforeEach(function(){
    module('surgeApp');
 })
 beforeEach(inject(function(mapBase){
    map = mapBase;
 }));
 it("adds a group", function() {
    expect(map.addNewGroup("WMS Layers", [])).toEqual(ol.layer.Group);
  })
})
```

Tosses this error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at he (src/webapp/libraries/js/openlayers-3.js:703:31)

I assume this has something to do with the map not initing correctly but not sure what the work around would be. It would be a shame if I couldn't test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone going down this very frustrating road, you need to add a div for the map. This is annoying because it covers up part of Jasmine so I did the following:

```
<div id="map" style="width:10px"></div>
```

That causes the map to be extremely small. You could make yours even smaller, I just liked to be able to make sure it was loading. After that, I was able to unit test my functions.